# TSQL syntax to feed results into subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm after some help on how best to write a query that does the following. I think I need a subquery but I don't know how to use the data returned in the row to feed back into the subquery without hardcoding values? A subquery may not be the right thing here?

Ideally I only want 1 variable `...WHERE t_Date = '2018-01-01'`

**Desired Output:**

[image]

The COUNT Criteria column has the following rules

Date < current row

Area = current row

Name = current row

Value = 1

For example, the first row indicates there are 2 records with `Date < '2018-01-01' AND Area = 'Area6' AND Name = 'Name1' AND Value = 1`

**Example Data:**

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/92ba3/4

Effectively I only want to return the first 2 rows but summarise the historic data into a column based on the output in that column.

[image]

Comment: Is the Excel screenshot meant to show the desired result? Or are you working in Excel? Looks like you need a self join

Comment: Yes the Excel screenshots show the desired result. The top 2 rows are the desired output but the entire SQL table are rows 2 to 66 in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use the cumulative sum functionality in ANSI SQL and SQL Server since 2012:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when t.value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by t_area, t_name order by t_date)
from t;
```

This actually includes the current row.  If you have only one row per date (for the area/name combo), then you can just subtract it or use a windowing clause:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when t.value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over
           (partition by t_area, t_name
            order by t_date
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
           )
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a self join to find records in the same table that are related to a particular record:

```
SELECT  t1.t_Date,  t1.t_Area,  t1.t_Name, t1.t_Value,
COUNT(t2.t_Name) AS COUNTCriteria
FROM Table1 as t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 as t2
ON t1.t_Area=t2.t_Area
AND t1.t_Name=t2.T_Name
AND t2.t_Date<t1.t_Date
AND t2.t_Value=1
GROUP BY  t1.t_Date,  t1.t_Area,  t1.t_Name, t1.t_Value
```

Comment: @pathDongle . . . A self-join is not the best way to solve this problem.